# Replace specific numbers that follow each other in a matrix

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix

I am working with survey data and i would like to replace specific values - that follow each other- in a data frame.

For  example

```
   v1   v2   v3   v4  v5
   0    2    0    0   55
   0    0    3    0    1
   3    0    1    1    2
   0    2    0    2    0
```

If I replace (0,2,0) with 1's and the rest of the data frame with 0's, the new matrix will look like

```
   v1   v2   v3   v4  v5
   1    1    1    0    0
   0    0    0    0    0
   0    0    0    0    0
   1    1    1    1    1
```

How can I do this to n-lenght specific number, i.e. (1,3); (1,2,4,5,8,2)?

Comment: Do you mean replacing (1,3) and (1,2,4,5,8,2) by ones and everything else by zeroes?

Comment: The parts "i.e (2,3); (2,7,5)." and "i.e. (1,3); (1,2,4,5,8,2)" are somewhat cryptic. "Replace consecutive numbers" - I don't see anything consecutive with the values you replace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you need to clarify your question a bit to make sure that we are answering it correctly.

My assumptions are that, you are matching a pattern (`c(0,2,0)`) in the example you show, and you are only matching the pattern across rows. That is, it cannot wrap from row 2, column 5 to row 3, column 1, nor will it check matches in the columns only.

If those assumptions are correct, then the following function will work. It replicates the example you provided, and returns a matrix. You can modify the replace value (`rep_val`) and fill values (`fill_val`), 1 and 0 in your example, respectively, with the optional parameters. This function could also be improved to be more elegant, but I think it works.

---

**Code**

```
replace_pattern <- function(x, pattern, rep_with = 1, fill_val = 0)
{
  n <- length(pattern)
  if (n > ncol(x))
    stop("pattern is longer than number of columns")

  new_x <- matrix(fill_val, nrow = nrow(x), ncol = ncol(x))

  # loop over each row
  for (rr in seq_len(nrow(x))) {
    # start matching the pattern at the entry = length of pattern
    # and look backwards
    for (cc in n:ncol(x)) {
      cur_cols <- (cc - n + 1):cc
      cur_vals <- x[rr, cur_cols]

      # if it matches the pattern, replace the values with specified value
      if (isTRUE(all.equal(cur_vals, pattern, check.attributes = FALSE))) {
        new_x[rr, cur_cols] <- rep_with
      }
    }
  }

  new_x
}
```

---

**Testing**

Using your example, and setting it to `xx`

`xx`:

```
v1   v2   v3   v4  v5
0    2    0    0   55
0    0    3    0    1
3    0    1    1    2
0    2    0    2    0
```

And then calling `replace_pattern(xx, c(0, 2, 0))` returns the second matrix you provided.

```
x2 <- xx
x2[2, 2] <- 1
replace_pattern(x2, c(1, 3))
```

Returns:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    1    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

And

```
xx3 <- rbind(xx, c(1, 2, 4, 5, 8))
replace_pattern(xx3, c(1, 2, 4, 5, 8))
```

Returns:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    1    1    1    1    1
```

Finally, `replace_pattern(xx, c(1,2,4,5,8,2))` will fail because the pattern is longer than the number of columns.